# jpa/hibernate noob: join fetch does not work properly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-rest

A little bit silly question I guess, but I do not know why it does not work. My goal is to get a list of parents with children (in one request) where children's date is between request parameter from and to. I get the right parent object, but children object is not fetched with it.

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
@Data
public class Parent implements Serializable {

...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Repository**

```
@Query("select p from Parent p JOIN FETCH p.children child where " +
        "(child.date between ?1 and ?2)")
List<Parent> findCustom(@Param("from") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) Date from, @Param("to") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) Date to);
```

**Update**:

here is the result of the request

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "parent" : [ {
      "name" : "name",
      "category" : "UNASSIGNED",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/json/parent/10"
        },
        "parent" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/json/parent/10{?projection}",
          "templated" : true
        },
        "children" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/json/parent/10/children"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/json/parent/search/findCustom?from=2016-01-14T07:35+0000&to=2017-01-14T07:35+0000"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Fetch join doesn't do much when you have `FetchType.EAGER`. What is the actual question here? What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is I get only parents without children object, my goal is to get parents with encapsulated children objects in it

Comment: So the children list is empty? Or you only get the parents that have 0 children? In either case, has nothing to do with fetch join.

Comment: I added my current response. So I get the right parent (which has children and the date is between "from" and "to"), but the child object is not encapsulated

Comment: The Child class implements Serializable also?

Comment: Do you have a getter for children? Does your Child class have getters? Does the children have any values? By the way, do you have a class that is both a rest service and a jpa-repository? yikes.. This might just be due to json serialization..

Comment: Child class implements also Serializable. Parent and child have getter and setter (lombok's @Data annotation), child has many attributes and all of them are present. I solved the problem right now with a projection, but nevertheles I am asking myself why foin fetch does nothing :( if I change fetchType to LAZY, join fetch does nothing also :-(

Comment: You should debug in order to figure out whether it's the JPA query returning something wrong, or if its the json creation..

Comment: The most basic DEBUG of any JPQL query is to look at the SQL generated. Have you?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("select p from Parent as p,Child as c " +
        "where (c.date between ?1 and ?2)"+
         " and c.parent.id = p.id " )
```

try this out

Comment: If I use this query I have the same problem -> no child object in the response